# Java Iterator is skipping half elements

Tags: java, csv, iterator

I wrote a small scripts to read from CSV in java. It takes a CSV, and push some values from the CSV into an HashMap. My CSV has 110 records ( 109 without the header ) however i get an HashMap with 54 values. When i debug, i can see that at each iteration, a line from my CSV is skipped.

Here's the code

```
package **CENSORED**.utils;

import com.day.cq.dam.api.Asset;
import com.day.cq.dam.api.Rendition;
import com.day.text.csv.Csv;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;

public class DateFormatUtils {

  private static String dateFormatCsvPath = "/content/dam/csv/country_date_format.csv";

  public static String getDateFormatByLocale(Locale Locale, ResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
    Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource(dateFormatCsvPath);
    Asset asset = res.adaptTo(Asset.class);
    Rendition rendition = asset.getOriginal();
    InputStream is = rendition.adaptTo(InputStream.class);
    HashMap<String, String> localeToFormat = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Csv csv = new Csv();

    try {
      Iterator<String[]> rowIterator = csv.read(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        String[] row = rowIterator.next();
        String country = row[1];
        String locale = row[4];
        String dateFormat = row[6];
        localeToFormat.put(locale.toLowerCase() + "_" + country.toLowerCase(), dateFormat);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Here are few screenshot of my debug

at 1st iteration, the line 2 of my CSV gets added into my hashmap. The header have been skipped.
[image]

At 2nd iteration, the line 5 gets added to my hashmap, but lines 3-4 aren't.
[image]

At 3rd iteration, the line 8 gets added to my hasmap, but lines 6-7 aren't.
[image]

At the end i end up with 53 elements in my hashmap while i expect 109.
[image]

Here's also a sample of my CSV :

```
ISO 3166 Country Code,ISO639-2 Country Code,Country,ISO 3166 Country Code,ISO639-2 Lang,Language,Date Format
ALB,AL,Albania,sqi,sq,Albanian,yyyy-MM-dd
ARE,AE,United Arab Emirates,ara,ar,Arabic,dd/MM/yyyy
ARG,AR,Argentina,spa,es,Spanish,dd/MM/yyyy
AUS,AU,Australia,eng,en,English,d/MM/yyyy
AUT,AT,Austria,deu,de,German,dd.MM.yyyy
BEL,BE,Belgium,fra,fr,French,d/MM/yyyy
BEL,BE,Belgium,nld,nl,Dutch,d/MM/yyyy
BGR,BG,Bulgaria,bul,bg,Bulgarian,yyyy-M-d
BHR,BH,Bahrain,ara,ar,Arabic,dd/MM/yyyy
BIH,BA,Bosnia and Herzegovina,srp,sr,Serbian,yyyy-MM-dd
BLR,BY,Belarus,bel,be,Belarusian,d.M.yyyy
BOL,BO,Bolivia,spa,es,Spanish,dd-MM-yyyy
BRA,BR,Brazil,por,pt,Portuguese,dd/MM/yyyy
CAN,CA,Canada,fra,fr,French,yyyy-MM-dd
CAN,CA,Canada,eng,en,English,dd/MM/yyyy
```

Finally a last screenshot that shows that my CSV has correct EOL at their line
[image]

This is the `csv.read()` function, a class made by Adobe for AEM :

```
    public Iterator<String[]> read(InputStream in, String charset) throws IOException {
        if (charset == null) {
            charset = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
        }

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(in, 4096);
        this.input = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
        return this.read();
    }
```

Comment: Look at the stacktrace printed by the catch.

Comment: @Tarik No Error is thrown the code run smoothly

Comment: Are the newline characters consistent from line to line?

Comment: Write a test app that reads all the lines in an array.

Comment: @Tarik they are, i added a sc in the OP

Comment: Generally, the code you show is just a sample. I see you have a lot of classes. Please provide us at least all the necessary information. Cause here is a pattern skipping 2 rows each time.

Comment: @Aristotle it's AEM specific code before my try catch. What it does is just retrieve a resource from a specific path, it's boilerplate to fetch a resource and read its value. I included the full code.

Comment: The most likely culprit is the CSV reader then. If the CSV reader skips lines...

Comment: What is this `Rendition` class? That making some magic and returns `InputStream`??

Comment: @Tarik https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/text/csv/Csv.html That's the CSV class, it's made by adobe so i kinda doubt this is the issue here ( it's probably used by a ton of person in a lot of different settings )

Comment: @Aristotle once again it's AEM boilerplate code used everywhere in an AEM application. This is the documentation on how Adapter works if you're curious https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/sling-adapters.html

Comment: @JorelAmthor Well, when troubleshooting, I check everything, even what seems unlikely.

Comment: @Tarik I edited my post to add the `read` function from the CSV class, pretty classic.

Comment: As I can see from the 3rd iteration screenshot, again it skipped 2 lines at the 4th iteration. `country= "BA" locale= "sr"`. So for sure here is a pattern. Something is wrong with your reader.

Comment: Where is the read() method, the one with no parameters.

Comment: Inside the read method you posted, the variable *in* is declared again.

Comment: Are you sure that you are reading the csv file that you are expecting to read? The csv file that you show us has a path ending in `core/utils/csv/country_date_format.csv`, but your reader read a csv file with the path `/content/dam/csv/country_date_format.csv`

Comment: Check what the result is at this line `String[] row = rowIterator.next();` - if you've got more than the expected number of columns (`row.length`) then suspect your CSV reader is treating \n\r [Windows EOL] differently from \r [unix EOL] ...

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with another solution since i wasnt able to use this one. For perennity, i was developing this for an AEM project; i decided to leverage the Generic List Item in ACS-common to get a dictionnary with all the values i needed instead of reading from a CSV. As @Artistotle stated, there is def something wrong with the reader so i'd advise against using `com.day.text.csv.Csv;`